# String Constructor_networking

Tags: java

One of the constructor defined in String class is `String(char chars[],int startindex,int *numChars*)`, but i came across this `String(p.getData(),0,p.getLength())`.

*Note:p has reference of DatagramPacket Object.*

**Since getData() returns byte array of data contained in the datagram,it should give an error.But to my surprise it does not give error.**

Why is this so? Please explain.

Comment: This is C++, not java, as there is no `int *` in the String constructor.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman, how come you say so? The `*`...`*` is probably just a failed attempt to format the text.

Comment: Wait...sorry, it's the OP typo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a constructor that takes a `byte[]` as well:

[`String(byte[] bytes, int offset, int length)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5b%5d,%20int,%20int%29)

> *Constructs a new String by decoding the specified subarray of bytes using the platform's default charset. The length of the new String is a function of the charset, and hence may not be equal to the length of the subarray.*